# Gradle - uploadArchives generated snapshot is different from createJar

Tags: gradle, groovy

With my build.gradle file I am creating a jar file using a createJar task, which I later upload using an upload using an uploadArchives task.

The project is in groovy, structured like:
/src/main/groovy/package.name
/src/test/groovy

It's a test jar file, where the main class is in /src/test/groovy and it uses for processing classes from /src/main/groovy/package.name

The createJar task works and creates the jar that I need correctly.

So far so good.

The problem is when I run uploadArchives, which generates a snapshot.jar and it only contains the classes from /src/main/groovy/package.name

Why are the 2 jar files different ?

How can I make uploadArchives to upload the jar from createJar (or at least include the test classes as well & run it using the main class specified in createJar) ?

In build.gradle I have something like :

```
apply plugin: 'groovy'
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'maven'

sourceCompatibility = 1.5

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

artifacts {
    archives file: file('./build/libs/name-'+version+'.jar'), name: 'name', type: 'jar'
}

task createJar(type: Jar) {
    classifier 'test'
    from sourceSets.test.output

    manifest {
        attributes 'Implementation-Title': 'Gradle Jar File',
                   'Implementation-Version': version,
                   'Main-Class': 'MainClassName'
    }
}

uploadArchives {
    repositories {
        mavenDeployer {
            repository(url: "http://url/snapshotsFolder/") {
                authentication(userName: "user", password: "pass")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You could apply your `Jar` task configuration to the task created by the `java` plugin (`jar`) instead of the one you created on your own (`createJar`).

Comment: @lu thanks for the response, but I am not sure i understand

Comment: I've added an answer with an example.

Answer (score 0):

To extend my comment, let me add an example:

```
jar {
    classifier 'test' 
    from sourceSets.test.output
    manifest { 
        attributes 'Implementation-Title': 'Gradle Jar File', 'Implementation-Version': version, 'Main-Class': 'MainClassName'
    }
}
```

This will configure the task `jar` of type `Jar`, which is created by the `java` plugin.